# Asset pipeline require and relative images paths in css

Tags: css, image, relative-path, asset-pipeline

I have some js library bundled with css and images.

in assets/stylesheets/awesome-library/awesome-library.css we see something like

```
background-image: url("some-image.png")
```

if we'll write in our layout this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "awesome-library/awesome-library" %>
```

Browser will fetch http://example.org/assets/**awesome-library/some-image.png**

But if we'll require awesome-library/awesome-library in our application.css:

```
//= require awesome-library/awesome-library
```

Browser will fetch http://example.org/assets/**some-image.png** (404 of course)

I tried to rewrite awesome-library.css to scss (using image-url), but in result css url like `/assets/some-image.png`.
I do not want to merge library's images and all other images and, really, do not want to change library's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `@import "awesome-library/awesome-library.css";` in your application.css

Comment: Good answer, but...I need to add awesome-library.css to assets compile list, also browser really will fetch 2 css files (and so there is no real difference between my realization using `stylesheet_link_tag` and yours)

Comment: The difference it that my solution doesn't change the html in any way. It just takes one extra http request. But what is it you actually want to achieve?

Comment: I want a way to implement aggressive caching (so user will load just **one file** and until any of css changed, user will not make new requests for css to server). Also in your idea there is no fingerprint in css file name, so I can't say to user "hey, keep this file next 100 years and do not fetch it again". (But yeah, I can implement fingerprint in application.css.erb using something like `@import "<%= asset_path("awesome-library/awesome-library.css")%>";`). So currently I use this way (@import + asset_path), thx to you. But it will be better if we can incapsulate all css in one file.